# Real Introduction to Apache Karaf

Tags: apache-karaf

We are looking to use Karaf, but their introduction/quick start (main Karaf website) has almost nothing to say about deploying apps to the container - I know, amazing yet true. Anyone know of a useful introduction for someone completely new to Karaf? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you looked at the wrong places the, cause the user and developer dokumentation tells you that you either deploy your artefacts either by dropping in the deploy folder, by installing with osgi:install url,  by adding/installing features and so forth. I really recommend RTFM, it's there. In case you still didn't find what your looking for ask the users mailing-list.

At this [site](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/index.html) you'll find the Karaf Online Documentation

Comment: You mention dropping into the deploy folder - where is that in the sites online doc? It may seem obvious (after you install) but it should at least be mentioned, it's kind of an important detail. And I did RTFM.

Comment: The documentation regarding the folders and a "brief" hint about the purpose can be found at http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/directory-structure.html -- this case it's the deploy folder for hot-deployment

Comment: More details on how deployment works: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/deployer.html

Comment: How to use the Console http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/using-console.html -- use osgi:install for deployment from the shell

Comment: a complete list of all commands available: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/commands/commands.html

Answer (score 0):

A google for keywords: **java, osgi bundle, activator**

will turn up examples of how to code for Karaf. For example: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html?page=2

Also, after learning the keywords (OSGI and bungle) I noticed netbeans has a project type of "OSGi Bundle". How nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful links:

- How to use Karaf console: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/console.html
- Christian Schneider has some useful tutorials as well: http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials
- Jean-Baptiste Onofre blog (search on Google)

Pay attention that Karaf 3 has slightly different shell commands, so make sure that you are pointing to the right Karaf or you learn how to translate Karaf 2.x commands to Karaf 3.